# PostgreSQL passing variable in function for select into

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers

We are creating trigger before inserting in users relation that call below function.
In this function we are selecting from users depends on function argument and insert into a temp table for logging.
But result of execute select is null!

```
create or REPLACE function auth._role_policy_admin(_role text, _province text, _type user_group, _services json) returns void
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
    _contract_id INTEGER;
    _user_id INTEGER;
    _test INTEGER;
  BEGIN
      if _type = 'customer' then
         EXECUTE 'SELECT id FROM auth.users WHERE users.username = '' ' ||  _role || ' '' ' INTO _user_id;
         INSERT INTO auth.logs(user_id, role) VALUES (_user_id, _role);

      end if;
  END;
$$;
```

Comment: Why are you using the extra quotes (' ').. Do you really need it?

Comment: Of course 2 quotes means that use quote in a string format

Comment: Remember that if your trigger is executed before inserting the user, the new user will not be available in the database yet.

Comment: in our where clause we need to check if the username equals to _role and I think the problem is type casting of _role, we are seeking for a solution

Comment: Maybe the `like`operator can solve this problem with type casting.. Also try to manually cast is using `_role::text`